# Should I return a member vector by reference when I need to modify them in other place?

Tags: c++, oop, refactoring

In the following code, the method in B will modify the member vector of A. In order to implement it, I return the vector by reference. Are there any other better practices?

```
class A {
 public:
  vector<int> &GetData() { return data_; }
 private:
  vector<int> data_;
};

class B {
 public:
  void Method(A *a) {
    vector<int> &data = a->GetData();
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: The idiomatic way is `public: std::vector<int> data;`. Your approach has no encapsulation advantage and an over-engineering disadvantage.

Comment: "What is the idiomatic way" tends to be "primarily opinion based" and therefore off-topic. Try to rephrase it in a way that a best answer is possible and can be objectively judged as such.

Comment: One question to ask yourself is why `Method` is a part of `B` and not a member of  `A`.

Comment: @BoPersson: Their responsibilities are not same or closely related.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do it multiple ways, there isn't a standard way to do it.

You could do it like you said, or make the member public:

```
class A {
public:
 std::vector<int> data_;
};

class B {
public:
void Method(A* a) {
  a->data_[0] = 0;
  (...)
};
```

You can also make B a friend class of A, and then make `data_` private, like this:

```
class A {
private:
 friend class B;

 std::vector<int> data_;
};

class B {
public:
void Method(A* a) {
  a->data_[0] = 0;
  (...)
};
```

It really depends on how will you use the `data_` member.